Downloading only a certain number of publications using Pybliometrics
I'm using pybliometrics.scopus.ScopusSearch
I have the following issue:
Basically I only want, say 10 of the top search results. If I use ScopusAPI directly I can pass this parameter into "count".
I tried to do the same with pybliometrics, for example
s = ScopusSearch(query=query, view="STANDARD", count=10, download=True, verbose=True, subscriber=False)

However the following error is raised
pybliometrics.scopus.exception.ScopusQueryError: Found 37,806 matches.  The query fails to return more than 5000 entries.  Change your query such that it returns fewer entries.

How do I solve this?

After some exploration, I think the original implementation is not capable of doing this. I'm not sure why, but the source code outputs n/count instead, n being the number of total query results. You have to modify the source code to output what I wanted here.

you could put minimal working code with example query so we could simply copy and test it.

Despite the name, parameter count currently does not restrict the number of results to be returned, but the number of results per page during the pagination. It will still return the same results, just make more calls.
Seeing this, we're going to change the behaviour, which should go live with 4.1 soon.

Thanks a lot! After digging into the source code and modifying some lines it then works fine, not a major issue.
